# SQL query: HAVING date = MAX(date) doesn't work

Tags: mysql, impala

I tried to write a sql query to get the latest date of  the same id. So I write:

```
select id 
from table 
where id = 10
having table.date = MAX(table.date)
```

But it still returns me with the same result as just

```
select id 
from table 
where id = 10
```

I don't know why, we can't use having this way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `Having` without a grouping.

Try this:

```
select id 
from table AS A
where id = 10 AND table.date = (select MAX(table.date)
                                from table as B
                                where a.id = b.id)
```

Comment: Ah, thanks very much.. But MAX is not something about grouping?

Comment: @YilingLiu no, not necessary ;)

Comment: @YilingLiu if it is correct please Mark my answer as correct. Thanks